# Model has strange shade points

Tags: modeling, topology

I did a bit of re-topo and suddenly when I smooth the model it creates this weird effect seen below:
[image]

[image]

I've 'Removed Doubles' and made it 'Double Sided'. (I've also selected 'Auto 
Smooth' which has helped a little but I still get these weird cut off points.

You can see it near the top right section of the eye:
[image]

Would love to know the solution to this problem as it really messes with the render.

Here's the .blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34280

Comment: Looks like your mesh is separated, coul you upload .blend file ?

Comment: could be some edges extruded inside. Look close in wirframe view.

Comment: It could be internal faces as mentioned by Bithur.  Maybe you could try increasing the Merge Distance for Remove Doubles.  It's set pretty low by default and doesn't catch very many overlaps.  A good way to tell if that's happening is to select and drag one of the vertices to see if the others come along with it.  Press escape to cancel the movement.

Comment: I've checked multiple times and there're no duplicate vertices, edges or extrudes. Neither are they separated. I'll upload the .blend file so you guys can take a gander.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply that some of your normals that are wrong...

Select all faces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals (or from the *3d view* header use *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*).

This can happen when creating faces and selecting vertices in a different order than blender expects.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! Learn something new about Blender every day!