# I use the key " F3 " to " Bridge " the coffee cup and the handle , the modeling looks unnatural

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

[image]

I follow the lesson on YouTube " Part 2, Level 3: Complete Modelling - Blender Beginner Tutorial " ,  step by step , but when I use the key " F3 " to " Bridge " the coffee cup and the handle , the modeling looks unnatural , and the bridge's line looks no smooth .
Could you mind teach me how to fix this problem of the " bridge "❤️Thank YOU!!!!!❤️

Comment: Check if selecting all vertexes and pressing Shift+N helps.

Comment: Thank You!!!!!!!‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️❤️❤️❤️

Comment: Ok, I will mark it as a duplicate than. You can study more here [Model has strange shade points](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24469/model-has-strange-shade-points) but keep in mind that Ctrl+N has been changed to Shift+N

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!! ‍♀️‍♀️❤️❤️❤️❤️You let me learn more knowledge in blender , and its very useful !!!! I appreciate the time you spent finding that information for me.Thank you for giving me this information❤️❤️❤️

Comment: By the way, the F3 key is no hotkey for the Bridge tool, it just brings up the search bar. So it's more or less for every tool and not necessary to mention, as long as there's no specific problem with the search itself ;)

Comment: Eureka !!!! I didn't know that before !!! Thank you for your teaching and guidance!!!❤️❤️❤️